# Merge multiple arrays into one 2d array with associative rows

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, mapping, merging-data

This is what I'm trying to arrive at:

```
array (
  'category_0' => 
  array (
    'count' => 12,
    'avg' => 11,
  ),
  'category_1' => 
  array (
    'count' => 14,
    'avg' => 13,
  ),
  'category_2' => 
  array (
    'count' => 16,
    'avg' => 15,
  ),
  'category_3' => 
  array (
    'count' => 18,
    'avg' => 17,
  ),
)
```

From the following:

```
$category = 
array (
  0 => '9',
  1 => '10',
  2 => '11',
  3 => '12',
)
```

and:

```
$count =
array (
  0 => '12',
  1 => '14',
  2 => '16',
  3 => '18',
)
```

and:

```
$avg = 
array (
  0 => '11',
  1 => '13',
  2 => '15',
  3 => '17',
)
```

I've arrived at the `$count` and `$avg` variables by performing some other methods using a `foreach` on the `$category` and the `array_map` function.  Now I need to rejoin everything per the intial example.  I've tried `array_merge()` but am unable to get it to work correctly.  The key name of 'category_x' is unimportant.  I'm not even sure if it's possible to get the final result in the order I need it.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/352329).  If you are already using other loops to populate these arrays, then you should probably populate this final desired result while inside of those earlier loops. It is unclear why you mention but abandon the `$category` data.  This desired result can be simply achieved with mapped calls of `get_defined_vars()`. https://3v4l.org/EMLQG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a combination of `array_keys` and a `foreach` loop, you can easily accomplish this.

**Example:**

```
<?php

$category = array (
    0 => '9',
    1 => '10',
    2 => '11',
    3 => '12'
);
$count = array (
    0 => '12',
    1 => '14',
    2 => '16',
    3 => '18'
);
$avg = array (
    0 => '11',
    1 => '13',
    2 => '15',
    3 => '17'
);

$out = array();
$key = array_keys($category);
foreach ($key as $key) {
    $out["category_{$key}"] = array(
        'count' => isset($count[$key]) ? $count[$key] : 0,
        'avg' => isset($avg[$key]) ? $avg[$key] : 0
    );
}
print_r($out);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [category_0] => Array
        (
            [count] => 12
            [avg] => 11
        )

    [category_1] => Array
        (
            [count] => 14
            [avg] => 13
        )

    [category_2] => Array
        (
            [count] => 16
            [avg] => 15
        )

    [category_3] => Array
        (
            [count] => 18
            [avg] => 17
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

I might be misunderstanding, but I think you're over-thinking this. Just use a for loop to build a master array:

```
<?php
$category = array (
  0 => '9',
  1 => '10',
  2 => '11',
  3 => '12'
);


$count = array (
  0 => '12',
  1 => '14',
  2 => '16',
  3 => '18'
);

$avg =  array (
  0 => '11',
  1 => '13',
  2 => '15',
  3 => '17'
);

$final_array = array();
for($i=0;$i<count($category);$i++){
    $final_array['category_'.$i] = array(
        'count' =>  $count[$i],
        'avg'   =>  $avg[i]
    );
}

print_r($final_array);

?>
```

Also, keep in mind that your code will throw a syntax error because the last element cannot be followed by a comma.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do anything like that with a function call, you will need to loop manually. If this could cause a problem because of the number of records, then you may wish to re-think and refactor.

```
$res = array();

// category values are irrelevant, but it is easier than using array_keys
// (and never use for loops when you can use foreach: foreach can be 20% faster
foreach($category as $key=>$val)
{
    // use manual concatenation and it is generally about 1.5% faster
    // and clearer to your compatriots
    $res['Category_'.$key] = array(
          // since key maps to the same key for all, then simply use that 
          // for the lookup
          /*
            if you KNOW that there will always be a key in $count and $avg
            then use the following:
          */ 
          'count' => $count[$key],
          'avg' => $avg[$key]
           /*
             otherwise you will need to use this:
          'count' => isset($count[$key])?$count[$key]:0,
          'avg' => isset($avg[$key])?$avg[$key]:0
           */
    );
}
// $res now has everything you're looking for.
```